# ReactJS Background Image not Showing

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

The code inside the image below suppose give me the background. But it did not work. I don't get it why?

[Image to the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjYWG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your stylesheet you should reset the margin and padding of the `html` and `body` tags and set the `height` and `width` respectively to `100vh` and `100vw` like this

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

#root {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

.sign-in-container does not get 100% elevation. Because React have Root and you component inside root div on DOM. Root's height is not 100%. It is "auto".

You have to use "height: 100vh" instead of height: "100%" this project.

Comment: Thanks but why do I get these white edges: https://i.imgur.com/l42owx6.png